# AttributeError: module 'apache_beam' has no attribute 'DoFn'

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, attributeerror

Can someone help to fix the attribute error, the code is given below for your reference.

Ps.Note It has the class DoFn, but still it throws the attribute error, PFB screenshot for the same.

```
import apache_beam as beam

class Func1(beam.DoFn):

    def process(self, x, *args, **kwargs):
        for _ in range(x[1]):
            yield dict(zip(['name','value'],x))

with beam.Pipeline() as pipe:
    row = (
        pipe
        | beam.Create([
            ('apple', 1),
            ('banana', 2),
            ('orange', 3),

        ])
        | beam.ParDo(Func1())
        | beam.Map(print)
    )
```

[image]

Comment: simple, the module named `beam` which you have imported doesn't contain any such class named `DoFn`

Comment: No, it has the class DoFn

Comment: The docstring your IDE is showing you for `DoFn` seems to be that of the [`appache_beam.transforms.core.DoFn`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.27.0/apache_beam.transforms.core.html#apache_beam.transforms.core.DoFn) type. Other than a few minutes reading of the (very complicated) docs, I don't know the beam API at all, so I don't know if it's also supposed available through a shorter path. One last suggestion is to double check that you're importing the `apache_beam` module you expect, not some random `apache_beam.py` file you have sitting around in your module search path.

Comment: I checked other sample codes in github , the usage is correct , but for some reason it is giving this error. I am not importing any other file named as apache_beam

Comment: I unfortunately can't tell you why you're getting that issue, but I can confirm that `beam.DoFn` is expected to work, you are using it correctly. I think what Blckknght mentioned is likely, that the import statement is importing the wrong apache_beam module (or maybe there's some other subtle difference in your environment).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to resolve it by myself, I imported the DoFn class directly and it worked fine, Below is the modified code,

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam import DoFn

class check(DoFn):
    def process(self, element, *args, **kwargs):
        for _ in range(element[1]):
            yield dict(zip(['name','value'],element))


with beam.Pipeline() as pipe:
    row = (
        pipe
        | beam.Create([
            ('apple', 1),
            ('banana', 2),
            ('orange', 3),

        ])
        | beam.ParDo(check())
        | beam.Map(print)
    )
```